# Using EWS to delete entire meeting series from a single occurence

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Currently I am trying to do some cleanup on my organizations room calendars within Exchange 2007. As it is right now, I am exporting all calendar items within the last year to an list that contains them all.

I am searching through the list, looking for calendar items whose names contain the phrase `Canceled:`.
Once I find a meetingthat meets this criteria, I do a `HardDelete` on the item.

This works fine for deleting canceled meetings that are between todays date and 365 days ago.

However, some users decided in ~2010 that they were going to book a recurring meeting from now until the end of time. We now have a policy in place that won't allow booking for more than 366 days in advance, however this is a new policy so old ancient recurring meetings are still present.

So how do I delete the entire series when my search within the last 365 days pulls up a single occurence?

---

A side-question that can bypass my question completely would be:

> How do I, or is it even possible to, query for EVERY calendar event on the calendar?

In this case, Its okay if I delete every single occurence of a meeting as it will capture all of the events in my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Calendar Paging (which expands the recurring Appointments) then you will be limited to both the max number of appointment you can return and also the time period you can return for. The easiest way to get the Master instance within your current method is to use the BindToRecurringMaster method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment.bindtorecurringmaster(v=exchg.80).aspx all you need to do is feed it the ItemId of one of the occurances.

Otherwise what you could do is use a FindItem with a restriction to find any recurring appointments that don't have an End date and remove them eg

```
# Bind to the Calendar Folder
$folderid= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Calendar,$MailboxName)   
$Calendar = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)

$Recurring = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DefaultExtendedPropertySet]::Appointment, 0x8223,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Boolean); 

$sfItemSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo($Recurring,$true) 


#Define ItemView to retrive just 1000 Items    
$ivItemView =  New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(1000)   
$rptCollection = @()
$fiItems = $null    
do{ 
    $psPropset= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)  
    $fiItems = $service.FindItems($Calendar.Id,$sfItemSearchFilter,$ivItemView)   
    if($fiItems.Items.Count -gt 0){
        [Void]$service.LoadPropertiesForItems($fiItems,$psPropset)  
        foreach($Item in $fiItems.Items){ 
            if($Item.Recurrence.HasEnd -eq $false){
                ## Do something of place other tests to ensure you don't delete the wrong thing
            }
        }
    }
    $ivItemView.Offset += $fiItems.Items.Count    
}while($fiItems.MoreAvailable -eq $true)
```